# How to calculate occurrence percentage with respect to available options

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a polls app where user will give their input according to available choices

```
# they can be different also `len` of `choices` list can be changed
choices = ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Leave Blank']
```

And the user_input will 1 item from the choices. like

```
new_user_input = 'Agree' # that could be anything from choices
```

I've been struggling with returning accurate results with out running multiple iterations.

Lets see what I'm trying :

```
def find_occurency_percentage(list_):
    return {i: round(list_.count(i)/len(list_)*100, 2)  for i in list_}
```

Running this function in Scenario 1:

```
# Fist Scenario 
all_user_inputs = ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', ]
new_user_input = 'Agree' # that could be anything from choices
all_user_inputs.append(new_user_input)
print(find_occurency_percentage(all_user_inputs))
'''
current result = {'Agree': 66.67, 'Disagree': 33.33}
expected result = {'Agree' : 66.67, 'Disagree': 33.33, 'Leave Blank' : 00.0}
'''
```

My problem is I'm unable to handle it so that the result should be according to all original `choices`. Not just only `all_user_inputs`

Here are more examples to understand the problem with running compiler https://godbolt.org/z/eTqYWd54e

Comment: There was mistake in the expected result I updated it .

Comment: Welcome to SO! So you're expecting the words to match exactly and approximately before returning the occurence percentage?

Comment: You could use a class from standard library: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: If a user never enters "Leave blank", it won't be present in `_list`

Comment: Lets say there are 3 choices and results should be 3 items with there concurrency percentage in user inputs

Comment: Yes if user never enters "Leave blank" it won't be present in _list but I want his occurrence percentage  in the results which would be Zero

Comment: What? Why would "Leave blank" *not* be present in `_list`? I'm saying that if the user never enters it, it won't be present, and therefore uncountable.

Comment: Because I'll be storing user responses in the list that only have the user inputs and if 'Leave blank' was never chosen from any user, so it wont be in `new_user_input` which is a `list_`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be more understandable

```
from collections import Counter

def find_occurency_percentage(list_, choices):
    counts = Counter(list_)
    return {k: counts[k] / len(list_) for k in choices} 

choices = ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Leave Blank']
all_user_inputs = ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Agree']
print(find_occurency_percentage(all_user_inputs, choices))

# {'Agree': 0.6666666666666666, 'Disagree': 0.3333333333333333, 'Leave Blank': 0.0}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over choices instead:

```py
{choice: round(100 * _list.count(k) / len(_list), 2) for choice in choices}
```

This has the added benefit of only iterating once over a much smaller input space, `choices`, as opposed to a theoretically much larger space, which is the user inputs.